# Minha aplicação MVC 5 insere no banco de dados, mas a view não exibe a lista de registros

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Aparece o seguinte erro: O item de modelo inserido no dicionário é do tipo'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[SistemaHome.Models.Usuario]', mas esse dicionário requer um item do tipo 'SistemaHome.Models.Usuario'.

Já pesquisei por aqui mesmo sobre o erro e a solução de alterar na view para List ao invés de IEnumerable não resolveu. Eu consigo inserir no banco, porque a minha Action e View de Create funcionam,  porém a Index não.

Minha Controller:

namespace SistemaHome.Controllers
{
    public class UsuariosController : Controller
    {
        private Banco db = new Banco();

```
    // GET: Usuarios
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View(db.Usuario.ToList());
    }

    // GET: Usuarios/Details/5
    public ActionResult Details(int? id)
    {
        Usuario usuario = new Usuario();

        if (id > 0)
        {
            usuario = db.Usuario.Find(id);

            if (usuario == null)
            {
                throw new Exception("O registro " + id + " não foi encontrado");
            }
        }
        return View(usuario);
    }

    // GET: Usuarios/Create
    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        var user = new Usuario();

        return View();
    }
```

Minha View Index:
[image: Imagem da View Index]

Meu Model:

[Table("Usuario")]
    public partial class Usuario
    {
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
        public Usuario()
        {
            HistoricoProposta = new HashSet();
        }

```
    [Key]
    [Display(Name ="Código do Usuário")]
    public int IDusuario { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(100)]
    [Display(Name ="Nome Completo")]
    public string Nome { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(50)]
    [Display(Name ="CPF")]
    public string CPF { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name ="Data de Nascimento")]
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    public DateTime Nasc { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Informe um usuário válido", AllowEmptyStrings = false)]
    [StringLength(40)]
    [Display(Name ="Login")]
    public string Login_Nome { get; set; }

 //   [Required(ErrorMessage = "Senha Incorreta", AllowEmptyStrings = false)]
    [DataType(System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.DataType.Password)]
    [StringLength(10, MinimumLength = 4)]
    [Display(Name ="Senha")]
    public string Senha { get; set; }

    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<HistoricoProposta> HistoricoProposta { get; set; }
}
```

Minha classe de conexão com o Banco:
  public partial class Banco : DbContext
    {
        public Banco()
            : base("name=Banco")
        {
        }

```
    public virtual DbSet<Categoria> Categoria { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Fornecedor> Fornecedor { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<HistoricoProposta> HistoricoProposta { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<PerfilUsuario> PerfilUsuario { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Proposta> Proposta { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<StatusTabela> StatusTabela { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Usuario> Usuario { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Categoria>()
            .Property(e => e.Tipo)
            .IsUnicode(false);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Fornecedor>()
            .Property(e => e.RazaoSocial)
            .IsUnicode(false);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Fornecedor>()
            .Property(e => e.Cnpj)
            .IsUnicode(false);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Fornecedor>()
            .Property(e => e.Cidade)
            .IsUnicode(false);

        modelBuilder.Entity<PerfilUsuario>()
            .Property(e => e.PerfilTipo)
            .IsUnicode(false);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Proposta>()
            .Property(e => e.NomeProposta)
            .IsUnicode(false);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Proposta>()
            .Property(e => e.Descricao)
            .IsUnicode(false);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Proposta>()
            .Property(e => e.ValorProposta)
            .HasPrecision(18, 0);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Proposta>()
            .Property(e => e.LocalArquivo)
            .IsUnicode(false);

        modelBuilder.Entity<StatusTabela>()
            .Property(e => e.StatusNome)
            .IsUnicode(false);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Usuario>()
            .Property(e => e.Nome)
            .IsUnicode(false);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Usuario>()
            .Property(e => e.CPF)
            .IsUnicode(false);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Usuario>()
            .Property(e => e.Login_Nome)
            .IsUnicode(false);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Usuario>()
            .Property(e => e.Senha)
            .IsUnicode(false);
```

Como posso resolver isso? Alguém pode me ajudar?

Comment: Pode ajustar o código? Ele está desformatado dentro da tag de script. Aproveita e coloca para nós a sua view da index.
O que estou entendendo é que você está colocando somente o IEnumerable...
Mas precisa colocar a sua classe em Lista. um exemplo: @model List<Usuario>

Comment: Coloquei uma imagem da minha view index. Sobre sua sugestão eu testei, porém não resolveu... @VainerCesario

Answer (score 0):

Tente forçar a o retorno de um IEnumerable.

```
var usuarios = db.Usuario.ToList();
return usuarios.AsEnumerable();
```

Answer (score 0):

Neste comando você não está buscando do banco o seu modelo.
Você está pegando a instância do modelo de usuários e dando um ToList().

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return View(db.Usuario.ToList());
}
```

Você precisa fazer uma consulta.

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
   return View(db.Usuario.FindAll().ToList());
}
```

Na tua view, que tu postou a foto vai ficar no topo a lista desse teu Model:

```
@model List<SistemaHome.Model.Usuario>
```

Comment: muito obrigada pela dica, porém não funcionou. Eu refiz a minha aplicação novamente mantendo o código original e o sistema funcionou. Acredito que tenha sido um bug do próprio VS, porque o erro que ele estava passando era algo que estava declarado corretamente.